# Use JwtBearerEvents with ActionFilter

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, controller

I'm having a hard time to use JwtBearerEvents with my custom ActionFilter that I use to authenticate users using JWT token by calling a class that contain the token validation logic.
The intention of using JwtBearerEvents is to log every attempt of logging whether successful or failed. Is it possible in my case to use JwtBearerEvents? because all documentation says that JwtBearerEvents is usually used with Authorize attribute.

I created a custom JwtBearerEvents class to log and configure it in the startup file but this class has never been triggered during authentication. any thoughts please? Thank you for your help. this is a sample code of what I have currently:

```
public interface IAuthenticationService
{
    public bool ValidateTokenOrThrow();
}

public interface AuthenticationService
{
    public bool ValidateTokenOrThrow()
    {
        //logic of token validation where i use SecurityTokenHandler

        //....
    }
}

public class CustomActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService { get; set; }

    public CustomActionAttribute(IAuthenticationService authenticationService)
    {
        _authenticationService = authenticationService;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        var isValidToken = _authenticationService.ValidateTokenOrThrow(token); // this is an error as both parameters do not exist at this moment

        if (!isValidToken)
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
    }
}

public CustomJwtBearerEvents : JwtBearerEvents
{
    private readonly ILogger<JwtBearerEvents>_logger;

    public CustomJwtBearerEvents(ILogger<JwtBearerEvents> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;        
    }
    
    public override Task OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCodes.AuthenticationFailed;
                        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                        var err = this.Environment.IsDevelopment() ? context.Exception.ToString() : "An error occurred processing your authentication.";
                        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {err});
                        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
                    }
}

//Startup file
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        service.AddSingleton<CustomJwtBearerEvents>();
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.EventType = typeof(CustomJwtBearerEvents);
        });
    }

public HomeController : BaseController
{
    [CustomActionAttribute]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public GetHome() 
    { 
       return service.GetHome(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. It'll be great if you add an examples from your ActionFilter and it's registration from Startup.cs to the question. I think that there is a problem with registration your JwtBearerEvents class in authentication pipeline but we need details :)

Comment: @VadimMartynov please find a sample of my code in the edited question. thank you